# Backbonejs - Avoid parse after save

Tags: backbone.js

[Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) says,

> parse is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in
>   fetch, and save. The function is passed the raw response object, and
>   should return the attributes hash to be set on the model.

But i have customized parse function for my model. I want to execute it only when i fetch data not when i save data.

Is there a way to do it? I can check my response inside parse function. But is there any built-in option to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18243514/722238). Also check out [this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/2551).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from the backbone [source file](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-61) regarding saving a model:

```
var model = this;
var success = options.success;
options.success = function(resp) {
    model.attributes = attributes;
    var serverAttrs = model.parse(resp, options);
    if (options.wait) serverAttrs = _.extend(attrs || {}, serverAttrs);
    if (_.isObject(serverAttrs) && !model.set(serverAttrs, options)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (success) success(model, resp, options);
    model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
};
```

You could pass a custom option on your `save` like: `model.save(null, { saved: true })`, then in your custom `parse`:

```
parse: function(response, options) {
    if ( options.saved ) return this.attributes;
    // do what you're already doing
}
```

I haven't tested this at all, but it should at least get you started.

Answer (score 4):

Just pass a parse:false into the save method as an option.

```
m = new MyModel()
s.save(null, {parse: false})
```